# Как удалить tr через closest, используя event.target?

Tags: javascript, dom

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать удаление строки `tr` через нажатие иконку `fa-trash`. Вот здесь DOM, внизу опишу свой скрипт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот сам скрипт:

```js
var table = document.querySelector('.table');
table.addEventListener('click', checkAct);

function checkAct(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName === 'TD' && target.className !== 'delete') {
    editTd(target);
  } else if (target.tagName === 'TD' && target.className === 'delete') {
    deleteTr(target);
  }
}

function deleteTr(target) {
  var tr = target.closest('tr');
  if (tr) {
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Имя</th>
    <th>Фамилия</th>
    <th>Удалить</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Иван</td>
    <td>Васильевич</td>
    <td class="delete"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Влад</td>
    <td>Анатольевич</td>
    <td class="delete"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="" class="name" placeholder="Введите имя">
  <input type="text" name="" class="surname" placeholder="Введите фамилию">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Добавить строку</button>
</form>
```

Когда я нажимаю на область `td`-шки строка `tr` удаляется, а когда нажимаю на иконку `fa-trash` скрипт не работает, я понимаю что ошибка с `target`-ом в аргументе функции `deleteTr`, но не могу разобрать что можно сделать.

Помогите как реализовать данный скрипт, и обязательно через метод `closest`. И если сможете поясните поподробнее, очень прошу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот :

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('.fa.fa-trash'))
    e.target.closest('tr').remove()
})

// или так
// document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', e =>
//       e.target.matches('.fa.fa-trash') ? e.target.closest('tr').remove() : {})
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Имя</th>
    <th>Фамилия</th>
    <th>Удалить</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Иван</td>
    <td>Васильевич</td>
    <td class="delete"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash">remove</i></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Влад</td>
    <td>Анатольевич</td>
    <td class="delete"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash">remove</i></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Логика дико простая, мониторя клик по таблице проверяем не нажали ли мы на нужную иконку, если да то удаляем строку

[matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)